# Rails I18n: error 'translation missing' when i try translate this words "off"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-i18n

Why I can't translate this word?

config/locales/pt-BR.yml

```
pt-BR:
  testing:
    off: 'Desligado'
    offff: 'Test'
```

rails console

```
> I18n.t 'testing.offff'
=> "Test"
> I18n.t 'testing.off'
=> "translation missing: pt-BR.testing.off"
```

Comment: try declaring it with `'off': 'Desligado'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Special words are restricted such as

> 'true, false, yes, no, on, off'

Juste change the key 'off' to something else, which is not restricted.

[The doc about booleans in YAML](http://yaml.org/type/bool.html)

Comment: Wow. I expected true & false to be restricted, of course, but why would yes, no, on, off be restricted? They're not part of the Ruby syntax. Is it specific to YAML?

Comment: Yes I added a link in my answer.